# changing parent entity in @PrePersist not saving changes

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have two entities: 
Parent 
(id,name,lastNumberOfChild)
and 
Child(id,number).

When I add a child to parent's list of children, a child gets new numer, parent entity property lastNumberOfChild is incrementing by one. I want this to happen in the moment when I do entityManager.merge(parent), before flush (it's important in the full case).
I've tried to do that with @PrePersist annotation on Child entity. It works only in a half. 
The property was changed by a @PrePersist method, but after that it haven't been saved to database.

Do you have any thought how I can achive this?

Thanks for every idea

Comment: That is odd, I would expect it to be picked up in prePersist, what version are you using?  Are you using field or property access?

Comment: I found that in @PrePersist you can't modify parent entity (the cause is optimalization). So I had to modify all entities before executing merge(entity). (I'im using eclipselink 2.3.2, property access).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that in @PrePersist you can't modify parent entity (the cause is optimalization). So I had to modify all entities before executing merge(entity).